# Foreign key assignment in Class based views

Tags: django, django-views

Basically I have a "node" detail page, from where I need to assign a new drive (for this given node - they need to be linked). The issue is to link "node" for DriveModelForm, which need to be assigned in the view. Whats wrong?
All the details are below.

Urls:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('<int:pk>/drivecreate/', DriveCreateView.as_view(), name='drive-create')
]
```

View:

```
class DriveCreateView(CreateView):
    template_name = 'create_drive.html'
    form_class = DriveModelForm

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('nodes:node-detail')

    def form_valid(self, form):
        drive = form.save(commit=False)
        drive.node = self.kwargs['pk']
        drive.save()
        return super(DriveCreateView, self).form_valid(form)
```

Model:

```
class Drive(models.Model):
    manufacture = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    model = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    drive_type = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    capacity = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    node = models.ForeignKey(Node, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Node(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    ... many more ...
```

Form:

```
class DriveModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Drive
        fields = (
            'manufacture',
            'model',
            'drive_type',
            'capacity',
        )
```

Error:
**Cannot assign "1": "Drive.node" must be a "Node" instance.**

Answer (score 0):

View should be slightly adjusted and reference to Node and linked to id.

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    drive = form.save(commit=False)
    drive.node = **Node.objects.get(id=self.kwargs['pk'])**
    drive.save()
    return super(DriveCreateView, self).form_valid(form)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
from .models import Drive

def form_valid(self, form, pk):
     drive = form.save(commit=False)
     drive.node = Drive.objects.get(id=pk)
     drive.save()
     return super(DriveCreateView, self).form_valid(form)
```